# Test Exchange EWS on public server

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

Is there any public Exchange server (emulator) that I can use to test / experiment with my Exchange Web Services implementation?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there is anything free. It will be much easier to create your own VM. You'll need Windows Server 2003 with Domain Controller role and Exchange 2007. Installation is pretty trivial.

After you've done it, go to Exchange Management Console to create a mailbox, then navigate to https://server/owa to create some messages and https://server/ews/exchange.asmx to access the EWS web service.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/EwsAccess/input).